# How to implement a stop button

Tags: java, javafx, while-loop, javafx-8, software-design

The code below is in java the run button works okay and sends a message to my number when it gets the error i have selected and then it displays the errors in a TextboxArea but the stop button does not end the loop it exits the program.How can i implement the stop button

```
/*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
package postilion_error_checker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author kithinjid
 */
public class checker_guiController implements Initializable {

  static Logger log;
  static Handler file_handler;
  static Connection conn=null;
  static Statement st=null;
  static ResultSet rs=null;
  static int i = 0;
   int counter=0;
  static boolean checker=true;
   String number; 
   String Sink_node; 
   String Rsp_code;
   int Respose_code;



    @FXML
    private  TextArea TA;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextField get_NO;
    @FXML
    private TextArea preview;
    @FXML
    private Button run;
    @FXML
    private Button stop;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox item;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox item2;


    @FXML
   private void handleRUNAction(ActionEvent event) 
    {
         scheduled();

        System.out.println("execution started");
        String out="execution started";
        TA.appendText(out+ "\n");
    } 
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) 
    {
         number=get_NO.getText();
         Sink_node=item.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
         Rsp_code=item2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
         Respose_code=Integer.parseInt(Rsp_code.substring(0, 1));
         preview.appendText("RECEIVER:"+number + "\n");
         preview.appendText("SINK NODE:"+Sink_node + "\n");
         preview.appendText("RESPONSE CODE:"+Rsp_code + "\n");
         preview.appendText("=========================\n");
         get_NO.clear();
    }
    @FXML
    private void handlestopAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        dbclose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {

    } 
       private  void dbconnect()
    {
        String username="Postilion";
        String password="Password12";

        String hostname="jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.112.6;databaseName=realtime";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(hostname,username,password);
            System.out.println("TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+":connected to database");
            String out_data="TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+":connected to database";
            TA.appendText(out_data+ "\n");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

       private  ResultSet check_00(String query1)
    {
        dbconnect();     

        try
        {
        st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(query1);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return rs ;
    }
       public void dbclose()
       {

           counter=0;
      try {
          conn.close();
          st.close();
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(checker_guiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

       }
  public void scheduled()
    {


    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
   public void run() 
   {
    while(checker==true)
    {
//    log=logger.getLogger("my logger");
//    try {
//    file_handler=new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\kithinjid\\Google Drive\\interswitch\\NetBeansProjects\\POSTILION_ERROR CHECKER\\dist\\logg.txt");
//    SimpleFormatter formatter=new SimpleFormatter();
//    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter);
//    log.addHandler(file_handler);
//    } catch (IOException ex) {
//    log.info(dateString("HHmmss"));
//    Logger.getLogger(POSTILION_ERROR_CHECKER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//    } catch (SecurityException ex)
//    {
//    Logger.getLogger(POSTILION_ERROR_CHECKER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
////    }
    String query="SELECT TOP 10 [tran_nr]\n" +
"      ,[gmt_date_time]\n" +
"      ,[time_local]\n" +
"      ,[date_local]\n" +
"      ,[sink_node]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_req_rsp]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_cmp]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_rev]\n" +
"  FROM [realtime].[dbo].[tm_trans_10]where sink_node ='"+Sink_node+"' ORDER BY tran_nr desc";
       dbconnect();


    try
    {
      ResultSet result=check_00(query);

       while(result.next()==true)
       {
          //loop for counter and displaying
      int response=Integer.parseInt(result.getString("rsp_code_req_rsp"));
     System.out.println(response);
     TA.appendText(response+ "\n");
     if (response==0)
     {
     counter++;
    if (counter==5)
    {
    System.out.println("TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+"--error respose code:91 of count:"+ counter+" to sink node:"+Sink_node);
    String output="TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+"--error respose code:91 of count:"+ counter+" to sink node:"+Sink_node;
    TA.appendText(output);
    send_sms(number,output);
    }
     }

       }
         dbclose();
         delay();
         counter=0;
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
                       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }
                    }
   },0,30000); 

    }
    public static void delay()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    private static String dateString(String formart)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formart);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
     public static void send_sms(String receiver, String text)
    {

        String app_name="Postilion_Error_checker";
        String sender_ID="VERVE";
        String user_Name="PostilionErrorChecker";
        String pass_word="Post4334dild";
       String output=sendSMS(receiver,text, app_name, sender_ID, null,user_Name, pass_word);
       System.out.println(output);
    }
      private static String sendSMS(java.lang.String recipient, java.lang.String text, java.lang.String appName, java.lang.String senderID, java.lang.String reference, java.lang.String userName, java.lang.String password) {
        org.tempuri.SMSGatewayWs service = new org.tempuri.SMSGatewayWs();
        org.tempuri.SMSGatewayWsSoap port = service.getSMSGatewayWsSoap();
        return port.sendSMS(recipient, text, appName, senderID, reference, userName, password);
    }
}
```

[this is the image of the program when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD5GO.png)

Comment: what else than quitting the program do you expect when calling `System.exit(0);`?

Comment: Why is this tagged `Swing`? What Swing code is present?

Comment: its tagged swing because javafx advanced from there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all that is java. Your project structure must represent something big, a- a business, a factory or even whole city with all its ecosystems. For now you have one brick and your brick is about 10 times bigger than the normal. Read about the SINGLE RESPONSIBILITY PRINCIPLE and you will start to implement the things much easier. Ok that was a nice off topic, and for your Question: 
System.exit() will kill your JVM so usually developers stay away from it. But if you insist on it- you can use it for "exit"/"close" button.

I see you have a recursive method. Maybe there should be an exit criteria with something like this:

```
if(isStopped)return
```

and replace your

```
System.exit()
```

with

```
isStopped = true;
```

and at the top of your class declare it as static for your first version.

```
public static boolean isStopped = false;
```

Comment: good one let me try this and i will revert as soon as possible